# silverlight scrollviewer height and width setup

Tags: silverlight

I am having problem understanding the scrollviewer in silverlight webpage. There are the usercontrol and grid "layoutRoot". My scrollviewer is set before the "Layoutroot" grid. It never worked properly. Even though I have other items at the bottom of the page, I could not scroll to them and could not see them. I have been playing with UserControl MinHeight, DesignHeight and minHeight of both LayoutRoot and Scrollviwer. Just have a hard time figuring out what is the best way to set it up.....

Comment: So have you set up you user control like <ScrollViewer><Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" /></ScrollViewer> ? This should work fine. If you have defined controls after the scroll viewer end tag then they may not be viewable....

Comment: I have <UserControl...                                                         MinHeight = "2000"DesignHeight="2000"....>                      <ScrollVieweer HinHeight="2000"...                                                        <Grid x:name="layoutroot".....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove min height and max heigh from all of the control because Silverlight takes care of all those things. What you need is to set VerticalScrollBarVisiblity to auto. By default it is disabled and you will be able to achieve what you want.

Cheers!
Vinod

Answer (score 0):

If the MinHeight properties are set too large then it will not be viewable on the screen and will be cut off. If you remove the MinHeight properties on both the UserControl and ScrollViewer then it should work fine.

Or if that doesn't work post your code so we can have a look.

Comment: I managed to make it work but still not ideal. Just playing around with minHeight generally.... Thanks.